# Strange error when combining Beamer, Animate, Tikz and Listings

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, errors, listings, animate

I'm working on some slides where I show how code is actually executed in Java. Therefore I'm working with the animate package to generate animations.

Without going into details, I've written a macro to help me generate an image for the animation. These images are generated by Tikz:

```
\newcommand{\methodexec}[4]{\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,5);
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]
\node[anchor=north west] (C) at (0,0) {\begin{minipage}{3in}\lstinputlisting[linebackgroundcolor={\ifthenelse{\value{lstnumber}=#2}{\color{green}}{}}]{programs/#1}\end{minipage}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,yshift=-5 cm]
\setcounter{tmpA}{1}
\foreach \n in {#3} {
 \coordinate (X) at (8.5,0.5*\arabic{tmpA});
 \node[pointerbox] (box\n) at (X) {};
 \node[pointerdot] (ptr\n) at (X) {};
 \node[anchor=west] (\n) at (box\n.east) {\small{\texttt{\n}}};
 \addtocounter{tmpA}{1}
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0.25,yshift=2.5 cm]
#4
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

An example of this macro is `\methodexec{code.java}{1}{}{}`

This all works fine except when I integrate these pictures into animate:

```
\begin{animateinline}{1}
\methodexec{code.java}{1}{}{}\newframe
\methodexec{code.java}{2}{}{}
\end{animateinline}
```

The compiler compiles the images correcly but reports some errors:

```
<a0,fr0> (./programs/code.java) ! Argument of \l@lstlisting has an extra }. <inserted text> \par l.11 }\newframe Runaway argument? ! Paragraph ended before \l@lstlisting was complete. <to be read again> \par l.11 }\newframe
```

Of course you can argue that I could ignore the errors. However I assume that there is something wrong with my code and furthermore Kile has the annoying behavior to open the `.vrb` file of the frame when an error is reported (I compile such frames in `fragile` mode).

EDIT: as MWE:

in `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,listings,lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage[controls]{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,fit}
\lstset{language=Java,basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
\tikzset{pointer/.style={->,thick,black},pointerdot/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0.125cm},pointerbox/.style={draw=black,rectangle,minimum size=0.25 cm}}
\newcounter{tmpA}
\newcommand{\methodexec}[4]{\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,5);
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]
\node[anchor=north west] (C) at (0,0) {\begin{minipage}{3in}\lstinputlisting[linebackgroundcolor={\ifthenelse{\value{lstnumber}=#2}{\color{green}}{}}]{programs/#1}\end{minipage}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,yshift=-5 cm]
\setcounter{tmpA}{1}
\foreach \n in {#3} {
 \coordinate (X) at (8.5,0.5*\arabic{tmpA});
 \node[pointerbox] (box\n) at (X) {};
 \node[pointerdot] (ptr\n) at (X) {};
 \node[anchor=west] (\n) at (box\n.east) {\small{\texttt{\n}}};
 \addtocounter{tmpA}{1}
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0.25,yshift=2.5 cm]
#4
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Some title}
\begin{animateinline}{1}
\methodexec{code.java}{1}{}{}\newframe
\methodexec{code.java}{2}{}{}\newframe
\methodexec{code.java}{3}{}{}
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And `code.java` (in the `programs` directory):

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Any ideas? A workaround (like for instance a variant of the `listings` package) is helpful as well.

EDIT2: It clearly has something to do with the `listings` package, because using `minted` solved the problem. But that doesn't explain why `listings` actually produces this error.

---

**John Wickerson adds:** I made a more minimal MWE, which rules out TikZ as the culprit. Beamer, Animate and Listings all remain suspects.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{code.java}
foo
bar
baz
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Some title}
\begin{animateinline}{1}
\lstinputlisting{code.java}
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error only occurs if the document is typeset with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, while `xelatex`, `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` work smoothly.

`animate` puts the animation frame content first into a box, using the LaTeX `\savebox` command. The filled box is then distilled into a PDF Form XObject using the command `\pdfxform` from pdfTeX. The last step fails, if the box contains `listings`-related material.

A minimal test case for `pdftex` and `lualatex`, without `animate` involved, is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{code.java}
foo
bar
baz
\end{filecontents*}

\newsavebox\listing

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Some title}

\savebox\listing{\lstinputlisting{code.java}}
\immediate\pdfxform\listing%

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Other engines don't use `\pdfxform` and therefore don't display this error.

As a workaround, I suggest to produce a separate PDF with the animation frames on individual pages, using the `preview` or `standalone` packages. This multipage PDF can then be animated using the `\animategraphics` command.